# AWS API Gateway with resource policy V.S. with VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, vpc-endpoint

I'm trying to create a private API using AWS API Gateway. In my understanding, I have 2 options to implement private API Gateway, 1) restrict sources with API Gateway resource policy and 2) restrict sources within a VPC with VPC Endpoint.

My question is: For option 1, can I set the condition in resource policy to allow traffics only from a specific VPC and achieve the same result as option 2?

```json
# API Gateway resource policy
{
  ...

  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals: {
      "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-123abc"
    }
  }
}
```

If yes, what's the different between them? What are the advantages to adopt VPC Endpoint to implement private API Gateway?

Comment: The option 1 seems doesn't work. It must create a VPC Endpoint to restrict a source VPC. Does condition "aws:sourceVpc" only work with VPC Endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the ways you can use to access private API gateways: [How to invoke a private API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html)

The condition that works with VPC endpoints in your case is **aws:SourceVpce**, with here the ID of execute-api endpoint that you deployed in your aws account. Here you can find list of AWS global condition context keys: [AWS global condition context keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html).

Comment: Can I use a VPC Endpoint in account A to access private API Gateway in  account B?
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Yes of course. In this case, you will need to authorize project A vpc-id in the account B private API Gateway resource based policy. The condition will look like:
"StringEquals: {
   aws:sourceVpce": "PROJECT_A_VPCE_ID"
 }

Comment: I read some solutions use VPC Endpoint Service as a entry for private API Gateway, and in another account, use VPC Endpoint to access the private API Gateway. What are the advantage of adopting VPC Endpoint Service?
(similar to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-private-cross-account-apis-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-privatelink/))